# 2D vectors input in c++

Tags: c++, vector, input, 2d-vector

I am a beginner in c++ so I was trying to solve a problem at codeforces and I have to make a 2d vector that have rows = 't'
column = 'n[i]' and I tried too make it.

But when I run the program it crashes with error "vector subscript out of range" and I don't know how to fix it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
int t;
cin >> t;
vector<int>n(t);
vector<vector<int>>x(t);

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            cin >> n[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < n[i]; j++) {
            cin >> x[i][j];
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Indent your code properly. Readable code is most important.

Comment: Hi, if any of the answers below suits your question, you should consider to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow), so that users know that the question is solved. There is no obligation for that.

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector<int>n(t);` constructs a vector with `t` integers. The integers are default constructed (actually not sure, but anyhows...), they are initialized with `0`.

`std::vector<std::vector<int>>x(t);` constructs a vector with `t` inner vectors. The inner vectors are default constructed, they are empty.

Trying to access elements that do not exist in `cin >> x[i][j];` invokes undefined behavior. `x[i]` is empty vectors.

You can use the constructor that takes another paramter, the initial value. For `t` sized inner vectors:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> x(t,std::vector<int>(t));
```

Alternatively you could call `resize`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < t; ++j) {
     x[i].resize(t);
```

Or `reserve` and `push_back`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < t; ++j) {
     x[i].reserve(t);
     for (int j=0; j < t; ++j) {
         x[i].push_back(42);
     }
}
```

Comment: In the code of the question, the index j runs from 0 to a user-given n[i], so the x is not  generally a square matrix (assuming this was the intent)

Comment: @francesco you are right, I didnt notice. Though the answer has also the alternatives that OP can directly apply

Answer (score 3):

With this:

```
vector<vector<int>>x(t);
```

you initialize a vector with t elements, where each element is a `std::vector<int>` which is initialized with the default constructor.
The default constructor gives an empty vector.
So, what you have here is a `t x 0` matrix, t lines and 0 columns.

When you access the vector x with

```
x[i][j]
```

you are asking to get the i-th element of x, which is a `std::vector<int>`, and from this, you want the j-th element. But there are actually 0 elements.
Crucially, accessing the elements with `[]` [does not carry any bounds checking](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at). So the program will have undefined behavior.

In this part:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < n[i]; j++) {
        cin >> x[i][j];
```

you fill the element `x[i]` with `n[i]` ints. Knowing that this will be the size of `x[i]`, you can fix the program adding

```
    x[i] = std::vector<int>(n[i]);
```

before the `for (int j = 0; j < n[i]; j++)` loop.

Or you could, for every inserted number, [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) a new element

```
    for (int j = 0; j < n[i]; j++) {
        int el;
        cin >> el;
        x[i].emplace_back(el);
    }
```

(For this solution you should not insert `x[i] = std::vector<int>(n[i]);` before the loop on j).